# Why is there junk attached to the end of Microsoft's Ajax CDN files?

Tags: javascript

When I go to

> http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js

or

> http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js

I get this junk appended to the end of the file

```
ow);    0
```

Hex would be:

```
6f 77 29 3b 0d 0a 0d 0a 30 0d 0a 0d 0a
```

I know the EOL there but I don't know the other stuff. This seems internal to my network but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Has anyone seen this?

I've thought of sophos, iprism as candidates but was wondering if anyone else had this issue.

Comment: btw it happens on all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't get any of the *junk*. Seems like you are behind a *junky* proxy/firewall.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this happen with proxy servers in 2 conditions: when the mime type (`Content-Type`) is set incorrectly in the web server, and when the http headers (`Content-Length`) don't correctly include the length (missing or wrong values). I find that [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a great tool for troubleshooting such issues.